# How do I get image based on event in recycler view?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

**Solved! See bottom of post.**

I'm using an API, deserialize its `JSON` data to variables and present the data in a `recyclerView`. So far, so good, everything works. However, I would like to display a different image based on what event header is shown. For example event header A should have image A, event header B should have image B, and so on.

I have implemented code that I think should work, but for some reason it doesn't. On

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RVviewHolder holder, int position)
```

**I used the following code:**

```
if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "A") {
        iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_a );
    } 
if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "B") {
        iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_b ); 
}else {
        iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_c );
    }
```

The program runs without errors, logs show that `getTitle()` contains A, but only `drawable c` is shown. I have checked so that all images worked, and I have also tried similar code in the bind:

```
    iconImageView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.iconImageView );

    if (RVevent.getTitle() == "A") {
        iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_a );
        Log.i( TAG, "yepp");

    } else {
        iconImage.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_b );
        Log.i( TAG, "nope");

    }
```

The logic should work, but I must have missed something... am I explaining this well enough or is there more info I should provide in the question?

**Solution:**
Ok, so the solution to the problem was to add `.contains` at the end:

```
if (myList.get( position ).getTitle().contains( "A"))
```

Not really sure why though, since it was the same exact wording. Well, good for future reference :)

Comment: i answered your question, Please check and update @Joakim

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your logic , should be like this. Your code comparing B with C & A alone checking with if condition. Means first check with A then B with C.

```
      if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "A") {
         iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_a );
       } 
       else if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "B") {
         iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_b ); 
       }
       else {
        iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_c );
        }
```

Initialize of `reyclerview_row.xml` view inside `ViewHolder` not inside `OnBindViewHolder`
try with below code :

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView iconImageView ;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        iconImageView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.iconImageView );
    }
}
```

Your `onBindViewHolder` method should be like this :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

           if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "A") {
             holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_a );
           } 
           else if (myList.get( position ).getTitle() == "B") {
             holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_b ); 
           }
           else {
            holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_c );
            }

    }
```

Or, You can try with below code too

```
if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(myList.get(position).getTitle())) {
             holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_a );
           } 
           else if  ("B".equalsIgnoreCase(myList.get(position).getTitle())) 
           {
             holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_b ); 
           }
           else {
            holder.iconImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_c );
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek, I made the changes you suggested, but I still get the same result. The compiler skips all the `if` statements (I checked by putting logs in the blocks), and only display the image for the last `else` statement. Strange... I'll keep on trying. Let me know if you have any more suggestions. Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: i updated my code try again check & Reply @JoakimSjöstedt

Comment: Thanks, found the solution though. See main post :)